# At what age is a judge too old for the Sanhedrin?

Tags: halacha, beit-din-court, age

> A man who is advanced in years ... must not be appointed member of any Sanhedrin, since he is required to be compassionate. [Hil. Sanhedrin 2.2](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Mishneh_Torah%2C_The_Sanhedrin_and_the_Penalties_within_their_Jurisdiction.2?vhe=Torat_Emet_363&lang=bi)

This is based on several Mishnaic (Horayot 1.4) and Talmudic (Sanhedrin 36) sources (see [here](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Tosafot_Yom_Tov_on_Mishnah_Horayot.1.4.3?vhe=Mishnah,_ed._Romm,_Vilna_1913&lang=en&p2=Mishnah_Horayot.1.4&lang2=en)). Rashi, for example, vaguely mentions "*forgetting the suffering of child upbringing"*.

At what age is a judge too old and incompassionate to function in the Sanhedrin?

Comment: Refer to the Rashash on the mishnah there - sefaria.org/… - either it is understood to mean he is old that he can no longer have children and that is why he lacks the compassion or it means that he is literally old in years. I don't think there is definitive age bracket listed?

Comment: I think the problem is to be appointed only. After he is appointed, there is no forced retirement.

Comment: @N.T. According to the ShU"T HaRashba (quoted [here](https://www.sefaria.org/sheets/69757.63?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) ), it applies equally to being appointed anew, as well as an already appointed judge.